# Grails redirect while keeping form values

Tags: grails, redirect, model-view-controller, controller

I have a Grails action that does some custom validation by calling some services.  I have the messaging setup to work properly, but when I redirect back to the page I came from, all of my previously entered data is gone.  I don't want my users to have to fill out the whole form again because validation failed.

Here's what I have

```
if(addressValidationErrors){
   flash.message = "Invalid address entered"
   redirect (action:'checkout', params: params)
}
```

and while the message shows on the GSP and the redirect works as intended, but when I end up back on the page all the values are gone.

Comment: It is very helpful if you post your view code that demonstrate how you trying to fill their value back.

Comment: @user1690588 The issue is I'm not sure how to go about that part.  How do I load their values back?

Comment: `params` is available in view, so you try `${params.someVariable}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 chain(action:"checkout", model:[key:domainObjectWithError])
```

Your view must check the errors and display messages accordingly then.